# How to change image folders with mod_rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

At my webpage I have links to images like this:

```
img/123456765/mypicture.jpg (<img src="img/123456765/mypicture.jpg" />)
img/2534/anotherpicture.jpg
```

where number folder is lastmodified time of image file in seconds e.g. strtotime(filemtime(mypicture.jpg)). They are virtual paths for browser cache refreshing, not real paths.

I'd like apache to automatically change those links to urls like these:

```
img/mypicture.jpg
img/anotherpicture.jpg
```

Basically,I'd like to eliminate that number folder in image path.

Mod_rewrite instructions I'm trying to construct look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^img/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|png)$ img/ [L]
```

I'm new to mod_rewrite so I'm not sure if these instructions are correct. Can anyone correct me if I'm wrong here? I'd appreciate it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you want something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^img/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+/(.*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|png))$ img/$1 [L]
```

The regex `^img/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+/(.*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|png))$` has a backreference ($1) to the match `.*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|png)`, essentially anything after the string of numbers and letters after the "img/". This will rewrite:

```
img/123456765/mypicture.jpg to img/mypicture.jpg
img/2534/anotherpicture.jpg to img/anotherpicture.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jon! It helped me greatly! ^^